# Javascript GPS navigator API : OSGB36 Eastings and Northings

Tags: javascript, mobile, gps

I am using the Javascript Navigator API, to get my location from the GPS on my Android phone.

It returns Lat and Long as expected in WS84 values.

My problem is that the map I am plotting on is based on OSGB36 6 digit Eastings and Northings and I have many objects to plot and they all have OSGB36 references, so I can not change my reference base.

Is it possible to get Navigator to use a different Datum (if that is the correct term) for OSGB36.

If not can anyone advise, how I would convert the WS84 lat long to OSGB36 Eastings and Northings.  I believe the maths is very complex.

I have come across `gridRefUtilsToolbox()`, but that seems a lot of code for a single conversion, that will be run on a browser in a mobile phone, as I am already using a lot of memory with the data values of my objects.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert WGS84 to OSGB36](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551028/convert-wgs84-to-osgb36)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Had a brainwave this morning, just create a WS84 scale for my map - as well as an OS36GB - no conversion needed